# Error C2664: Cannot convert argument from initializer list to std:initializer list

Tags: c++, dictionary, c++11

I have a function `read()` that reads a file and store information into a map. However, whenever the function calls `map.insert()`, it gives me an error.

`Employee` and `Volunteer` are two customs classes with only a few variables.
For example, If I call

```
ifstream fin;
std::map<std::string, Employee*> employees;
fin.open("Employee.txt");
read<Employee, EMPLOYEE_SIZE>(fin, employees);
```

It gives the following error:

```
std::_Tree<std::_Tmap_traits<_Kty,_Ty,_Pr,_Alloc,false>>::insert(std::initializer_list<std::pair<const std::string,Employee *>>)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'initializer list' to 'std::initializer_list<std::pair<const std::string,Employee *>>'`.
```

Here is the function(Both `Employee` and `Volunteer` has the same base class:)

```
template <typename T, int T_LINE_SIZE>
inline void read(std::ifstream& in, std::map<std::string, T*>& input) {
    std::string name = "";
    std::string ID="";
    std::string line;
    double salary;
    while (getline(in,line)) {
        if (typeid(T) == typeid(Volunteer)) {
            name = line.substr(0, 19);
            ID = line.substr(20, T_LINE_SIZE);
            input.insert({name,new Volunteer(ID,name)}); //error happens here
        }else if (typeid(T) == typeid(Employee)) {
            name = line.substr(0, 19);
            ID = line.substr(20, 29);
            salary = std::stod(line.substr(30, T_LINE_SIZE));
            input.insert({ name,new Employee(ID, name, salary) }); //error happens here
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: First, show a [example] (what is `Employee` and `Volunteer`?) -- also can `Volunteer*` be converted to `Employee*`?

Comment: Unrelated: Why `std::ifstream& in` instead of `std::istream& in`?

Comment: "_`Employee` and `Volunteer` are two customs classes with only a few variables._" - If you make a [mre] you don't need to explain what they are.

Comment: @user202729 I believe so by typecasting, they have the same base class but I am not going to do that .

Comment: @TedLyngmo I use ifstream to read from a text file

Comment: If you use an `std::istream&` instead you can read from files too. You can then read from _any_ `istream`-based stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code:

```
template <typename T, int T_LINE_SIZE>
inline void read(std::ifstream& in, std::map<std::string, T*>& input) {
    std::string name = "";
    std::string ID="";
    std::string line;
    double salary;
    while (getline(in,line)) {
        if constexpr (std::is_same<T, Volunteer>::value) {
            name = line.substr(0, 19);
            ID = line.substr(20, T_LINE_SIZE);
            input.insert({name,new Volunteer(ID,name)}); 
        }else if constexpr (std::is_same<T, Employee>::value) {
            name = line.substr(0, 19);
            ID = line.substr(20, 29);
            salary = std::stod(line.substr(30, T_LINE_SIZE));
            input.insert({ name,new Employee(ID, name, salary) }); 
        }
    }
}
```

The reason is that you are using templates. Based on the type of `T` when you call `read()` function, type of `T` is incorrect in scope of one `if` condition for calling `insert()` method. This happens because all possible outcomes of code need to be checked at compile time for different types. But when you use `if constexpr`, that part of code is ignored at compile time, so incorrect part of code will not be seen during compiling code and your code compiles correctly.

Answer (score 1):

@Afshin has shown one way you *could* do this, but I'd suggest that it's probably not the best way to do the job, at least as a rule.

By distributing the logic a bit differently, you can end up with code that I consider quite a bit simpler.

I would start by overloading `operator>>` to read a an object of each class you need to store:

```cpp
struct Volunteer { 
    std::string name;
    std::string ID;

    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, Volunteer &v) { 
        std::string line;
        std::getline(is, line);
        v.name = line.substr(0, 19);
        v.ID = line.substr(20); // captures the rest of the line
        return is;
    }
};

struct Employee { 
    std::string name;
    std::string ID;
    double salary;

    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, Employee &e) {
        std::string line;
        std::getline(is, line);
        e.name = line.substr(0, 19);
        e.ID = line.substr(20, 29);
        e.salary = std::stod(line.substr(30);
        return is;
    }
};
```

I may have omitted other (possibly important) things from `Volunteer` and `Employee`--I've only included enough to read one from a file, and store the data we read.

With those in place, reading them from a file becomes quite a bit simpler:

```cpp
template <class T>
inline void read(std::istream &is, std::map<std::string, T *> &input) {
    T t;
    while (is >> t)
        input.emplace(t.name, new T(t));
}
```

In this design, `Employee`s and `Volunteer`s each know how to read their own data from a file, and the code that reads the records doesn't need to know the details of how each is read. This makes the code rather more extensible. For example, let's consider what happens when we add a further class for `Intern`. In your original code (as repaired by Afshin), you'd add a third leg to the `if`/`else if` chain:

```cpp
else if constexpr (std::is_same<T, Intern>::value) {
   // code to read and insert data for an Intern here
}
```

By contrast, with the design I'd advocate, all the code to deal with Interns would be in (or at least associated with) the Intern class itself:

```cpp
struct Intern {
    std::string name;
    std::string ID;
    bool paid;
    double salary;

    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, Intern &i) {
       // code to read data for an Intern here
    }
};
```

...So in this case, the code to read data from a file doesn't require *any* changes to work with a file of records for `Intern`s instead of `Employee`s or `Volunteer`s.